# Customizing table cells . Adding images and labels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've a table thats displaying some data.
There are some images drawn. And lots of labels. 
I was wondering is there a better way or am I doing something wrong? Any advice or tips welcome.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

//scores not ready yet so do not try and draw them
if (initializeScoresHappening)
{
    UILabel *teamVersusLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105,0, 100, 20)];
    teamVersusLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    teamVersusLabel.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
    teamVersusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [teamVersusLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:14]];
    teamVersusLabel.text = @"Initialising score data...";
    [cell addSubview:teamVersusLabel];
    [teamVersusLabel release];
}
else 
{
    //Draw the default cell background image for a normal sized cell
    UIImageView *backGroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableCellBackground.png"]];
    [cell addSubview:backGroundImage];

    int cellHeight = [self cellHeight:indexPath.row];

    int numberOfExtensionsNeeded = (cellHeight - TABLECELLBACKGROUNDHEIGHT) / TABLECELLBACKGROUNDEXTENSIONHEIGHT;

    // if cell is bigger than the default sized background image draw in extension images
    if (numberOfExtensionsNeeded > 0)
    {
        int i;
        for (i=TABLECELLBACKGROUNDHEIGHT; i<(cellHeight-TABLECELLBACKGROUNDEXTENSIONHEIGHT); i+=TABLECELLBACKGROUNDEXTENSIONHEIGHT)
        {
            UIImageView *backGroundImageExtension = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i, CELLWIDTH, TABLECELLBACKGROUNDEXTENSIONHEIGHT)];
            [backGroundImageExtension setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableCellBackgroundExtension.png"] ]; 
            [cell addSubview:backGroundImageExtension];
            [backGroundImageExtension release];                                      
        }

        int remainingArena = (cellHeight - i);
        if (remainingArena > 0 )
        {
            int yPos = i - (TABLECELLBACKGROUNDEXTENSIONHEIGHT -remainingArena);
            UIImageView *backGroundImageExtension = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPos, CELLWIDTH, TABLECELLBACKGROUNDEXTENSIONHEIGHT)];
            [backGroundImageExtension setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableCellBackgroundExtension.png"] ]; 
            [cell addSubview:backGroundImageExtension];                                          
            [backGroundImageExtension release]; 
        }
    }
    else 
    {

        int i = (cellHeight - TABLECELLBACKGROUNDEXTENSIONHEIGHT);
        UIImageView *backGroundImageExtension = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i, CELLWIDTH, TABLECELLBACKGROUNDEXTENSIONHEIGHT)];
        [backGroundImageExtension setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableCellBackgroundExtension.png"] ]; 
        [cell addSubview:backGroundImageExtension];
        [backGroundImageExtension release];         

    }

    // Get the match object that holds the game data
    Match *aMatch = [appDelegate.matchResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel * teamName1Label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,0, 145, 20)];
    teamName1Label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    teamName1Label.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
    teamName1Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [teamName1Label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:14]];
    teamName1Label.text = aMatch.teamName1;
    [cell addSubview:teamName1Label];
    [teamName1Label release];

    UILabel *teamVersusLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(145,0, 20, 20)];
    teamVersusLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    teamVersusLabel.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
    teamVersusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [teamVersusLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:14]];
    teamVersusLabel.text = @"v";
    [cell addSubview:teamVersusLabel];
    [teamVersusLabel release];

    UILabel *teamName2Label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,0, 145, 20)];
    teamName2Label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    teamName2Label.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
    teamName2Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [teamName2Label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:14]];
    teamName2Label.text = aMatch.teamName2;
    [cell addSubview:teamName2Label];
    [teamName2Label release];

    UILabel *theScoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 20, 80, 20)];
    theScoreLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    theScoreLabel.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
    theScoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [theScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:14]];
    theScoreLabel.text = aMatch.theScore;
    [cell addSubview:theScoreLabel];
    [theScoreLabel release];

    int xVal = 0;
    int yVal = 0;
    int numTeam1Scores = 0;
    int numTeam2Scores = 0;


    for(int i=0; i<aMatch.matchGoalCount; i++)
    {
        NSString *teamOneOrTwo = [aMatch.scorerOrderArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([teamOneOrTwo compare:@"1" ] == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            //draw team 1 goal scorer on left side
            yVal = 40+(numTeam1Scores*20);
            xVal = 5;
            numTeam1Scores++;
        }
        else if ([teamOneOrTwo compare:@"2" ] == NSOrderedSame )
        {
            //draw team 2 goal scorer on right side
            yVal = 40+(numTeam2Scores*20);
            xVal = 160;
            numTeam2Scores++;   
        }
        else
        {
            //error -.-
            break;
        }

        UILabel *theScorerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, yVal, 145, 20)];
        if (xVal < 50)
        {
            //NSLog(@" UITextAlignmentLeft ");
            theScorerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        }
        else
        {
            //NSLog(@" UITextAlignmentRight ");
            theScorerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        }

        theScorerLabel.textColor =  [UIColor blackColor];
        theScorerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [theScorerLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:12]];
        theScorerLabel.text = [aMatch.scorersArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [cell addSubview:theScorerLabel];
    }
}
return cell;
}
```

Also these cells should not allow the user to interact with them. The table is just able to scroll.

Thanks
-Code

EDIT

Ok is this the basic shell that cellForRowAtIndexPath: should have?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell==nil)
{
 // we dnt have this cell made yet so we need to alloc a new cell
 // and do some code to add data to the cell labels, images, buttons etc
}
else
{
// we already made this cell earlier so there is nothing to do just return the cell
}

// dnt be adding anything to the cell here because in the case the cell already exsists 
// you will just draw over stuff already in the cell
return cell;
}
```

Is that pretty much it?

Thanks again 
Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code doesn't reuse cells. This is not good, your tableview will be slow.

do it like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // try to dequeue a cell from the tableview, for reuse:
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // dequeue failed
    if (cell == nil) {
        // create new cell:
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        // you add your subviews here.
        // example:

        UILabel *theScoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 20, 80, 20)];
        theScoreLabel.tag = 42;
        theScoreLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        theScoreLabel.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
        theScoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [theScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:14]];

        // add to the contentView!!!
        [cell.contentView addSubview:theScoreLabel];
        [theScoreLabel release];
    }
    else {
        // Nothing to do here. Because in either way we change the values of the cell later.
    }
    // whatever happened before, we have a valid cell at this point.

    // you configure your subviews here.
    // example:

    Match *aMatch = [appDelegate.matchResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *theScoreLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:42];
    theScoreLabel.text = aMatch.theScore;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hmm a bit confused! if cell equal to nil then draw stuff in the cell and should there be an else for the case its not nil, just return the cell? Maybe i dnt follow what is going on there?

Comment: this is basic tableview knowledge, maybe you should go one step back and play a little bit more with "standard" cells. Anyway, I added some comments to the code.

Comment: if cell is equal to nil it means that a cell with the CellIdentifier couldn't be retrieved and that means it needs to create one(inside the if branch you will allocate and initialize your custom cell). after that you can send your data to the cell in order to display it. the else branch is not necessary because you will always have a cell(reused or one created in the if statement)